# Change recorded macro to affect current sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a macro that I use from time to time.  It successfully deletes the columns I want it to, but it doesn't sort the columns as I want.  When I debug the VBA, I see it references the original Excel spreadsheet I used to create the macro.

When I play this macro back on a different worksheet in the same file that is identical to the original, nothing happens.

What changes do I have to make to the VBA to get this to work on any worksheet?

Here is the VBA:

```
Sub HF_weekly_file()
'
' HF_weekly_file Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:N").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:H").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("J:Q").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("L:Y").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leads_1464523080").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leads_1464523080").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "F2:F73"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leads_1464523080").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "G2:G73"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leads_1464523080").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "D2:D73"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leads_1464523080").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "I2:I73"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leads_1464523080").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:M73")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You've correctly identified the problem: your references to the worksheet are hard-coded, i.e., you use the name of the sheet in your code rather than a dynamic reference to a sheet. As a result, when you run the code, it affects the worksheet named "Leads_1464523080" instead of the active sheet.

To make your code sort the active sheet instead, you need to change every instance of

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Leads_1464523080")
```

to

```
ActiveSheet
```

This will make the Sort commands apply to the active sheet in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is used to select a column, and then delete it.  It is the same code that is found at the start of your macro.  To edit this code, change the column letter to the column that you want.

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Note: when the first column is deleted, it shifts all of the other columns.  Example: if you want to delete columns A and C, if you delete A, C shifts to B so you would need to delete B.  This can be simplified if you remove columns from right to left as shifts do not have an effect then.